# Fair value of game involving obtaining Heads

Tags: probability

I don't know how to solve this question: You are playing a game with flipping a coin. You can play it as many times as you want until there is a head. At the nth time, when you get a head, they will pay the $2^n$ dollars. How much are you willing to play this game? What's the fair value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the famous [St. Petersburg's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).

If you have got a head in your first try, you will get $2$ dollars and the possibility for this case is $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence the first try has $1$ dollar expected income.

If you get a head in the second try, you will get $2^2=4$ dollars, but the possibility for this case will be $$\frac{1}{2} \text {(you get tail in first try)} \times \frac{1}{2} \text {(you get head in second try)} =1/4.$$
Hence the second try also has $1$ dollar expected income.

You can inductively prove that every try has equal $1$ dollar expected income. Since you may try it *ad infinitum*, the total expected income will be arbitrarily large, and this, theoretically, also should be what you would pay - that's why it is called as a paradox.

For further discussion trying to solve it, you can refer to the Wikipedia link I have given.